# Binding data with angular. (Calling method into a view)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to bind some data with angular, I made an example and it works but I'm having problems to integrate my stuff into another app.

This is the controller of that app

```
angular.module('app', ['dcafe.navigation','ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('HeadlineReportController', function($scope, $http, $interpolate, $filter, datafactory, d3Factory, $timeout){

    //code

    $scope.SendData = function(){

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/', data, config)

        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
            console.log("Success");
            console.log("Status code: " + status);

        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            //$scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                console.log("Error");
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.log("Headers: " + header);
        });

    };
    $scope.SendData();

    //MORE CODE

});
```

I was working with the SendData() function that was inside a controller, in my view I used ng-controller and then the ng-repeat, but things are different in the second app.

They call the controller at the begining of the view like this:

```
<span ng-controller="HeadlineReportController as vm">
```

so I tried to do the ng-repeat like in my workig app, like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in PostDataResponse.result"> </tr>
```

But as you can see in the controller above the $scope.SendData = function() {}

is part of the HeadlineReportController so in this case I dont know how to do my ng-repeat, I was thinking in something like this:

```
ng-repeat="data in SendData()"
```

But It's not working.

Comment: SendData() will not work because it is an async operation.  What happens if you use extend instead of assigning such as angular.extend( $scope.PostDataResponse, data); Or $scope.ShowData = function() { return $scope.ResponseDetails; }; with ng-repeat="data in ShowData()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using controller as syntax change $scope to 'this'

```
var self = this;
self.SendData = function(){

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/', data, config)

    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        self.PostDataResponse = data;
        console.log("Success");
        console.log("Status code: " + status);

    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        //$scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
            console.log("Error");
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.log("Headers: " + header);
    });

};
self.SendData();
```

And use your view model as declared on controller as

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.PostDataResponse.result"> </tr>
```

Comment: Thank's for your time.

This work, In the console Im getting the success message that I log but for some reason It's not displaying the data.

Im using "ng-bind" like this:

<td ng-bind="data.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW" style="text-align: left"></td>

Any idea of why is not displaying data?

Comment: Something is weird :(

This is how Im doing the binding:

                                    <tr ng-repeat="data in vm.PostDataResponse.result">
                                        <td ng-bind="vm.data.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW"></td>
                                    </tr>

But nothing is displayed on the screen

Comment: Sorry for my last comment... 
you don't need vm.data.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW 

<td ng-bind="data.merchMetrics.SALES_AMOUNT_LW" style="text-align: left"></td> is correct!

you can try force $digest using $scope.$apply() on your success callback of $http.post

Comment: heey!
I add the $scope.$apply() in the success callback like this:

        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.PostDataResponse = data;$scope.$apply();

            console.log("Success");

        })
But still getting no data in the view, the ws call is working because I can see the succes message in my console

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of declare and use the controllers. From the [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) documentation

> Two different declaration styles are included below:
>
> - one binds methods and properties directly onto the controller using
>   this: ng-controller="SettingsController1 as settings"
> - one injects
>   $scope into the controller: ng-controller="SettingsController2"
>
> The second option is more common in the Angular community, and is
> generally used in boilerplates and in this guide. However, there are
> advantages to binding properties directly to the controller and
> avoiding scope.

You will need to change the code in your controller to the following:

```
angular.module('app',['dcafe.navigation','ui.bootstrap']).controller('HeadlineReportController',
 function($http,$interpolate,$filter,datafactory,d3Factory,$timeout){

//code
var vm = this;

$vm.SendData = function(){

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/', data, config)

    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        console.log("Success");
        console.log("Status code: " + status);

    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        //$scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
            console.log("Error");
            console.log("Status: " + status);
            console.log("Headers: " + header);
    });
};
vm.SendData();
```

});

And your ng-repeat will change to
ng-repeat="data in vm.SendData()"

Answer (score 1):

They are using the Controller As syntax in the view when they say `<span ng-controller="HeadlineReportController as vm">`.

Controller As is something you should look in to; [John Papa has a good explanation here](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/).

From your view, you would then reference controller variables like `vm.SendData()`. Also, with Controller As, you will not have `$scope` variables in your controller.